# Fixed crop size after taking picture

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to implement some code I found online, but it does not seem to work properly and I cannot tell if I am missing something.

I am able to get to the CROP feature of the phone but the bounds for the crop are not fixed in any way. They can be manipulated, where I want them to be the max size of the image width.

The issue stems from intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

```
public void takePicture() {

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling
    // application
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);
    intent.putExtra("scale", true);
    intent.putExtra("scaleUpIfNeeded", true);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Comment: All this cropping *extra* for ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE is device (and/or ROM) specific. Note that your end-user can install another application to handle this intent at any time, which will or will not respect your crop extra.